# javascript validation for academic year like 2015-16

Tags: javascript

i want to give javascript validation for academic year, like(2015-16). I need validation like first 4 are the numbers after that '-' is mandatory after that two digits. I tried Regex for this but i got nothing to repeat error.
this is i tried.

```
/^[2-9]{4}+[-]+[1-9]{2}$/i
```

Comment: /\d{4}-\d{2}/ will do any 4 numbers followed by `-` followed by any 2 numbers.

Comment: @char It seems that OP is interested in only years after "millennium"

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak it can be modified to fit whatever criteria OP wants. OP didn't mention if they wanted it specifically to fit a certain date range. Not that difficult to strip the first and/or second digit etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Date` object for validating datetime string.

```js
var date = new Date('2015-16');
var year = date.getFullYear();
if (year && year > 2000) {
  alert('Valid academic year');
} else {
  alert('Invalid academic year');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should both test for regex and years are compatible

```
var regex = /^2\d{3}-[1-9]{2}$/;
var year = "2011-12";
var years = year.split("-").map(function(el){
   return parseInt(el)
})

alert(years[0]>=years[1] + 2000);
alert(regex.test("2011-12"))
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pLuqma9t/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want true validation (i.e. that you can't do things like `2016-99`), regex will not suffice.

```
function isAcademicYear(input) {
  // Split the input, and convert both sides to numbers
  const [first, second] = input.split('-').map(Number);
  const firstIsValid = first >= 2000 && first <= 9999;
  // Second is valid if it's larger than the last 2 digits of first
  // The reason we use ... % 100 twice is for the case of 2099-00
  const secondIsValid = second === (first % 100 + 1) % 100;

  return firstIsValid && secondIsValid;
}
```

Could have been shorter, but I've been verbose to make sure it's clear.